# C# indexof not working

Tags: c#

When I run this through the debugger the result for string `CL_S` and string `NA_S` are the  same value, which is 122.13.

Not sure why it does this since the `indexOf` is different - the second one does not exist.

```
text = "4R|1|^^^100^CL_S|122.13|38||||F|||20070628114638" 

string str = text;

try
{
    int a_first = str.IndexOf("^^^100") + "^^^100".Length + 1;
    string str_a = str.Substring(a_first);
    string[] words_a = str_a.Split('|');
    string CL_S = words_a[1];

    int b_first = str.IndexOf("^^^101") + "^^^101".Length + 1;
    string str_b = str.Substring(b_first);
    string[] words_b = str_b.Split('|');
    string NA = words_b[1];
```

Comment: I don't see any `NA_S` or `^^^101` in the input.

Comment: [Debug](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn) and check the values, You can can find the reason yourself.

Comment: I'm pretty sure IndexOf works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step through a debugger and look at the values of the variables.

Here's a quick analysis which should help point you towards the problem:

`a_first` has the value `12`

`str_a` has the value `"CLS_S|122.13|..."`

`b_first` has the value `6`  (Note that you are adding `-1 + 6 + 1`; the `-1` is from the `IndexOf` that doesn't have a match.  `IndexOf` is working just fine.)

`str_b` has the value `"^^100^CL_S|122.13|..."`

When you split either `str_a` or `str_b` on a `|`, the second element (index `[1]`) of both will be 122.13.

Answer (score 2):

In the second case the `IndexOf` call returns `-1`, and adding seven to that puts you at index 6.

When you use that in the `Substring` call you will get `^^100^` prefixed to the string, compared to the string from the first case.

As that doesn't contain any `|` characters, splitting will only give a different result for the first item in the array, and as you are getting the second item it will be the same as in the first case.

Answer (score 0):

Run this on IDEONE https://ideone.com/F6KDNS

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {

      string str =  "4R|1|^^^100^CL_S|122.13|38||||F|||20070628114638" ;


        int a_first = str.IndexOf("^^^100") + "^^^100".Length + 1;
        string str_a = str.Substring(a_first);
        string[] words_a = str_a.Split('|');
        string CL_S = words_a[1];

        Console.WriteLine(a_first);
        Console.WriteLine(str_a);
        Console.WriteLine(CL_S);

        Console.WriteLine();


        int b_first = str.IndexOf("^^^101") + "^^^101".Length + 1;
        string str_b = str.Substring(b_first);
        string[] words_b = str_b.Split('|');
        string NA = words_b[1];

        Console.WriteLine(b_first);
        Console.WriteLine(str_b);
        Console.WriteLine(NA);
    }

}
```

I got this:

```
12
CL_S|122.13|38||||F|||20070628114638
122.13

6
^^100^CL_S|122.13|38||||F|||20070628114638
122.13
```

So you can see that the second IndexOf returns `-1` => b_first is `6`. This means that you the two strings in both have their first break at

`CL_S|` & `^^100^CL_S|`

And thus both have second item = `122.13`

Comment: My first question on SO and I have to just say Thank You. I really appreciate the guidance. I